# How to "dispaly the table row value in alert box" using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

As I'm new to react, I don't know how to display the table row value in alertbox.
I have a text input in the row.  Whenever I try to onchange the textinput, an alertbox should display the respective row value.

The code:

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
class App extends React.Component {
  handleChange() {
    alert("hi");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Top left</td>
          <td>Top right</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bottom left</td>
          <td>Bottom right</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Comment: What you did works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-tdd-tk588?file=/src/App.js. Let us know what's the problem?

Comment: I have to display the entire row value in alert box,  im not able to achieve that. @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize a state which gets updated everytime an input value changes, than you can send the value of the input focused in the alert

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      valueOne: "",
      valueTwo: ""
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });

    alert(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Top left</td>
          <td>Top right</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.valueOne} name="valueOne" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bottom left</td>
          <td>Bottom right</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.valueTwo} name="valueTwo" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated a bit the code, let me know if this works

Comment: Thanks for the output. But I have display the entire row value during onchange of the textinput  @ Marc Charpentier